# Xtext: Crossreference inside names

Tags: xtext

I'd like to have a crossreference inside the name of my Objects.
In my language I will have this:

```
2. Sentence
....
2.a. sentence
    1. sentence
```

Where 2 is the name of "2. sentence"

Here I'd like that the name of "2.a. sentence" being "2.a" while "2", in "2.a", being a reference to "2. sentence".

I already tried:

```
(name = ([Step|StepName] '.' CHAR ))
```

and

```
(name = (step = [Step|StepName] '.' CHAR))
```

but I just got errors.

Now I'm looking for changing the implementation files generate by Xtext (I changed the getName() method) but didn't get the results that I want. Since the EObjects contained in "2.a" do not have "2" in then QualifiedName, just "a". If we look in "1. sentence" I would like it to has the QualifiedName "2.a.1"

Comment: you may also use IQualifiedNameProvider + Access to Node Model via NodeModelUtils to calculate the name of things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the solution of the problem you can see here:

> http://www.cs.ru.nl/J.Hooman/DSL/AdvancedXtextManual.pdf

But I will explain it.

First you will creat an IQualifideNameProvider that extends the original IQualifiedNameProvider. Inside this classe you will creat how your QualifiedName should be composed. Here is how I did:

```
class MyDslQualifiedNameProvider extends DefaultDeclarativeQualifiedNameProvider {
  @Inject
  IQualifiedNameConverter converter = new
  IQualifiedNameConverter.DefaultImpl();

  override QualifiedName getFullyQualifiedName(EObject obj) {
    if (obj instanceof HelloGreeting) {
      val nodes = NodeModelUtils.findNodesForFeature(obj,
                           MyDslPackage.Literals.HELLO_GREETING__PERSON);
      for (node : nodes) {
        val text = NodeModelUtils.getTokenText(node);
        if (text !== null) {
          return converter.toQualifiedName(text);
        }
      }
    }
    return super.getFullyQualifiedName(obj);
  }
}
```

This extend code will generate a QualifiedName that is the exactly text of your cross reference HELLO_GREETING_PERSON, if you want to compose you name you will need to get the names of your EObject and concatenate the strings to create the QualifiedName.

For example this is my code, that i add to compose my name:

```
var a = obj.eContainer();
var FN = (a as UseCase).getName() + "." + text + "." + (obj as Extension).getName();
```

Then you will need to change you RunTimeModulo adding:

```
override Class<? extends IQualifiedNameProvider>
bindIQualifiedNameProvider() {
   return typeof(MyDslQualifiedNameProvider);
}
```

inside you class RunTimeModule.

This work for me. Theses codes are exact extract from the PDF above, I just tried to help to understand what need to be done.